# custom tableview controller's cell text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom tableview controller which has 3 sections.

1 first section has a collection view.
Now I want to add text (which length is less than 1000 characters) to a first cell of 2nd section.

I plan to make that cell style basic, so I can add title.

1. How can I call `cell.title.text = myString`?

I mean I want something like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView.section == 2 and cell == 1 {
        cell.title.text = myString
        return cell
    }
}
```

2. because `myString` length is between 0 ~ 1000 words. How can I change the height of cell base on the length of `myString`?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: Have a look on `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` !

Comment: I don't use tableview, I use tableview controller with custom cell. therefore, my question is a bit different

Answer (score 1):

## First Question

First set an identifier for the cell. If you're using storyboards, put a value in the Identifier field in the Attributes Inspector when the cell is selected.

Let's say you set that identifier to `"basic"`. Then write something like the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        // Section and row numbers start from 0, like practically everything else
        // in Cocoa, so 1 is the second section, and 0 is the first row.
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basic")! // Get a cell from the table view
        cell.textLabel?.text = myString // Set the string
        return cell
    }
}
```

## Second Question

To allow the text field to increase in height when the string is long, just set the `numberOfLines` property of the label in the cell to a large number (or a number that you calculate somehow based on the length of the string). For example, in the method above, before `return cell`, insert this line:

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 1000
```

The `numberOfLines` property, according to its documentation, is the *maximum* number of lines to use for rendering text, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with setting it to a very large number. It will still resize based on the length of the string.

Comment: I need to return cell outside if condition.

Comment: @John Temporarily, to test my code, try adding `return UITableViewCell()` outside the `if` block. This will fix the error for now.

Comment: I got this error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @John That would be due to the force unwrap after the call to `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`. Are you sure you set the identifier of the cell correctly in the storyboard?